# Yarn: Installation error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, yarnpkg

I have next.js app, before deploying to stand it builds on company servers, where we use a proxy, respectively I'm using the proxy for yarn

```
yarn config set proxy http://xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
yarn config set httpsProxy http://xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
yarn config set httpProxy http://xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
yarn config set https-proxy http://xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
yarn config set https_proxy http://xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
yarn config set http-proxy http://xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
yarn config set http_proxy http://xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't help and I still see the error during the build

```
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
error /app/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments: 
Directory: /app/node_modules/sharp
Output:
sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.10.6/libvips-8.10.6-linuxmusl-x64.tar.br
sharp: Installation error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
```

It seems like there are no problems with packages that were installed from yarn registry.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, trying to install npm sharp package behind proxy failed on downloading libvips on ETIMEOUT.

You can download `libvips*.tar.br` from the link in error to your local computer and then move downloaded file to repository.
Then, in project root (where you run `npm i` command) create empty file named `.npmrc` and paste `sharp_libvips_local_prebuilds="libvips-#YOUR_VERSION_HERE#-#YOUR_ENV#.tar.br"` inside (just copypaste file name).

Note this is just what is in [sharp documentation](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#custom-prebuilt-binaries) **and in future, you may need to update the downloaded file** (eg when sharp version update and req. newer libvips). Or freeze sharp version.

Also, if your local env is different from server (windows x linux), it won't work (probably) - [check documentation](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#prebuilt-binaries) about this.

You can also try asking your IT (whose are taking care of proxy) if they can somehow add url of libvips source to "whitelist" so your local npm i command could access it.

Any better approach is welcome.

PS noted that youre using yarn instead npm so you will need `.yarnrc` or similar file instead `.npmrc`.